# how to sum result of count in sql query from one table and one column

Tags: sql

[image]

I need to sum the result of count of a column in one query.
Is it possible to have like this query?

`SELECT sum(count(pro_id)) from jalasat group by pro_id`

Comment: Your query does not make sense to me, the result would be the same as you want to count all of the pro_id

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation. [mcve] applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described. What are you trying to count?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned which SQL database you are using so you may modify this slightly to fit it to what you are using:

```
SELECT SUM(cnt) FROM (SELECT COUNT(pro_id) as cnt
FROM jalasat 
GROUP BY continent) as t1
```